# Wrap Menu on Html Page when Screen Width is Reduced

Tags: html, css

I am using media query in css to hide menu and show hyperlink and on click of hyperlink I am showing wrapped Menu. Is there Any Default way to do this so that it implements responsive design?

**Code**

```
<a id="advanced_menu_toggle" href="#mobile-advanced">menu</a>
<div class="row" id="mobile-advanced">
    <div class="span2">
        <a id="hide" style="font-size:x-large" href="#">Close</a>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <img src="test.jpg" style="position: inherit" width="50%" height="50%" align="right" />
    </div>
    <div id="Div2" class="span8" style="float: left">
        <br /><br />
        <a href="Techesperto.html" style="font-size:x-large">Home</a>
        <br /><br />
        <a href="About" style="font-size:x-large">About Us</a>
        <br /><br />
        <span>
            <nav id="nav" role="navigation">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" style="font-size:x-large">Partners</a>
                    <ul  style="position:relative" >
                        <li id="LM1" style="float:inherit"><a href="#" style="font-size:x-large">Laptops</a></li>
                        <li id="LM2" style="float:inherit"><a href="#" style="font-size:x-large">Monitors</a></li>
                        <li id="LM3" style="float:inherit"><a href="#" style="font-size:x-large">Printers</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </nav>
        </span>
        <br /><br />
        <a href="Contact.html" style="font-size:x-large">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    <a href="Services.html" style="font-size:x-large">Services</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/4AjRh/

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Responsive design in what sense? Be very specific.

Comment: Go to Website http://www.gatwickairport.com and resize screen to size 274*346  On resize The menu gets Wrapped to + sign On clicking Plus sign menu appers in form of list. I want To implement that utility

Comment: A good start would be showing us the relevant portion of your CSS, including what you've tried, and explain what's not working. Update your question rather than putting code or information in comments.